# Adding Records and Decreasing Quantity

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm starting programming in pl/sql and I have some problems. I'm making a database, which includes tables like:

```
TRAINS: ID_TRAIN, NAME, TYPE

CARS: ID_CAR, TYPE, SEATS, QUANTITY

TRAINS_W_CARS: ID_TRAIN (FK), ID_CAR (FK), QUANTITY
```

I want to make a procedure/function, which will decrease amount of available cars, when I add some to train.

For example: I have 50 available cars with 2 class, and when I add 5 of them to the some train, this amount will be decreased to 45.

To be honest, I don't really know how to go about it, because I have not done so complicated things this far.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, consider modifying the nature of what you're storing in the first place.

Currently it seems like you're storing *one* record which is a *count* of 50 "cars", and *one* record which is a *count* of 0 "train cars".  So you have to manually keep track of moving these counts from one record to another.  This is not only error-prone, but can get confusing fast.  Mostly because there's no actual record of what cars are where, there are just counts.

To update, you have to do the following:

- Decrement the car count by 1.
- Increment the train car count by 1.

Instead, consider something like the following...

- The `CARS` table has 50 records, each representing an actual car.
- The `TRAINS` table has 1 record, representing an actual train.
- The `CARS` table has a FK to the `TRAINS` table.  This identifies to which train that car belongs.  This value is nullable for cars which aren't currently connected to a train.

In this scenario, you have to do the following:

- Update the FK of the `CARS` record.

It's a single atomic operation which either succeeds or fails.  No half-committed data, no missing cars, etc.

Each record in your data should represent "a thing".  Not counts and descriptions of things, but actual things.  And in this scenario you also don't need that linking table, because "trains" and "cars" are inherently not many-to-many things.  (How can a car simultaneously be connected to two trains?)

Always consider the real-world concept being modeled in your data.  You have:

- A train, which can have many cars
- A car, which can have many seats
- A seat
- A passenger
- etc.

Build the relationships based on the actual real-world objects, not on the screens and reports of data that you want to see.  Those reports can be easily generated from the real-world data, but real-world data can't always be generated from flat reports.  (For example, in your current setup you can look at a report of how many cars are in a train, but you don't know which ones.)

Comment: A High-quality text-book answer! You've refreshed my fading DB design basics. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are inserting rows in your table manually or from some UI button click but you can do below:

Add a before/after insert trigger in your CARS table and in that trigger write whatever you have to modify in your TRAINS table.